# Log file not being generated/written to

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I previously had this working where it would log to a file on my C: drive however trying to get this working into a logs folder using the CATALINA_HOME environment variable doesn't seem to work.

CATALINA_HOME environment variable is set to `C:\apache-tomcat\bin` and I was hoping to store the logs in `C:\apache-tomcat\logs`

Have I done something silly with my configuration file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_DIR">${sys:CATALINA_HOME}../logs</Property>
        <Property name="ARCHIVE">${LOG_DIR}/archive</Property>
        <Property name="PATTERN">%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %X{id} %X{username} %-5level %c{36} %l: %msg%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${PATTERN}" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="FileAppender" fileName="${LOG_DIR}/application.log"
                     filePattern="${ARCHIVE}/application.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${PATTERN}" />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="uk.co" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org.apache" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </Logger>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: What is the issue here? Is the log file actually created/written onto, or is it merely in the wrong directory?

Comment: It's not being created at all, it was once but since I've tried to get it working using CATALINA_HOME it stopped...

Comment: I think a `/` is missing, no? (i.e. `${sys:CATALINA_HOME}/../logs`)

Comment: same problem with the forward slash :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by changing `${sys:CATALINA_HOME}` to `${env:CATALINA_HOME}`

Also added a missing `/` thank to [RC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180100/rc)